# Xcode: Issue adding localization to my project (Resource file / Reference language not found)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, storyboard

I'm trying to add a Spanish version for my app. I'm following several tutorials and they all get me to this point:

Screenshot from http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014
[image: Resource file - Reference language from Raywenderlich]

But when I try doing the same thing step by step in my existing project, I don't see any files to choose from:
[image: Resource file - Reference language from my own project]

What do I have to do so I can create/see this files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have marked your files as localizable first. Select file (e. g. a storyboard) and then click the Localize button. Then, you will have that files listed when adding languages.

Answer (score 0):

This really helped me as well.  The tutorial doesn't speak of this.  There is also a conflict if you have a fabric.io resource like TwitterKit that already has the files defined for all the languages.  But this got me to the next step.  Thanks,

Peter

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.